# Xchat broken after update / reboot

Tags: updates, reboot, xchat

Today, I did some updates to 12.04, as I do weekly. I forgot to look at the impacted packages, because it mostly is just fine.

After reboot, XChat does not spool through the freenode channels, consuming 90/100% CPU.

As a possible solution I backed up my log files and deleted the files from the directories that contained them.

Does anyone have suggestions to fix my XChat?

Answer (score 1):

I had made a backup of my home directory files.

I have reinstalled Xchat and removed the files from my home directory `~/.xchat2`.

After reinstallation I verified Xchat working again and restored some configuration files from my backup.

Case closed.